# create-react-app: Invalid tar header issue on create new app

Tags: npm, create-react-app

For some reason, I keep getting "invalid tar" error (image below).

[image]

This script used to work in the past. But as I am about to start a new project, it fails.
Here the solution that I've tried and it **not** working.

- Delete my node_modules folder
- Reinstall Nodejs and npm
- Delete npmrc file in AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

Comment: Ran into a similar issue w/ an existing project running `yarn install` on Mac.  The issue was node versioning.  Running `nvm use 12` solved the issue for me.  Not entirely related to this question, but since this was the first question that popped up on google when I looked up "invalid tar" with "node", it makes sense to add this as a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

try and update the create-react-app package using the npm .

delete test project files any if created due to previous command.

run the create-react-app command again with a proper internet connection and it should work.